# Set up combo box row source VBA returning error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up the row source for a combo box in Excel VBA but is returning the error

> 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim rngVendor As Range

    Set rngVendor = Worksheets("Lists").Range("N2:N" & _
    Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)

    frmNewVendor.cboVendor.RowSource = Range(rngVendor)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

rngVendor is declared as a range so it doesn't need the Range function

```
 frmNewVendor.cboVendor.RowSource = rngVendor
```